# Background-x position on stellar JS

Tags: jquery, css, stellar.js

I'm trying to get the background-x to have be at 50%, I've read the stellar documentation and seen the demo. Unfortunately it would change the x position to 50%. What am I missing?

This is my container for the image

```
<div class="break stageOne" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"></div>
```

This is my default stellar JS to get initiate

```
$.stellar({
    horizontalScrolling: false,
    verticalOffset: 0
});
```

My class which holds the background image

```
.break{
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: 50% 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 700px;
}
```

My background image

```
.stageOne{
background: url(http://matthewduclos.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/canoncine.jpg);
margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stellar.js is nothing to do with your problem.
This is because you use `background: url` after `background-position: 50% 0;`

Just replace it:

```
.stageOne{
background: url(http://matthewduclos.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/canoncine.jpg);
margin-top: 60px;
}
.break{
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: 50% 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 700px;
}
```

or use `background-image` instead:

```
background-image: url(http://matthewduclos.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/canoncine.jpg);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/raskalbass/XCBt2/)